# Open URL in text selected in field or on page, in separate tab in Opera

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, opera

I have just migrated from Google Chrome to Opera and one of the Chrome's functions, that I miss the most is the `Go to [url]` item in context menu, when I select a piece of text on page or in any field, and my selections contains a valid URL:

[image]

From what I can see, Opera offers URL-opening-related context menu items only on actual links, but not on selected text, that is an URL address in fact:

[image]

Is there any Opera extension to fill this gap? I know, that I can [install Chrome extensions in Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/), but since mentioned functionality is in core Chrome, then I don't expect to find something like that in [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/open%20url?_category=extensions).

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 We can? You have pointed me to a **six and a half year old** blog entry. Did you notice, that we have 2015 already? From, what I can recall, Opera has dropped the idea of separate window for configuration for about two years or more. So "solution" provided by you is at least that long not valid.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually an answer or solution, but more like workaround. You can select text containing URL in any field, and then press following sequence of keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy selected URL to clipboard,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open new tab or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open new window,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to execute "*Paste and Go* functionality.

"*Paste and Go*" isn't mentioned in [official documentation](http://help.opera.com/opera/Windows/1918/en/fasterBrowsing.html), but can be found in `Settings > Shortcuts > Configure shortcuts` list in Opera.